# Google Spreadsheet vlookup in validation drop-down

Tags: validation, google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I want to operate with ids, and not with data that related to id.

For example:

Sheet `details` has this data:

```
  | A           | B        |    
1 | category_id | category |
2 | 0           | Web      |
3 | 1           | Mobile   |
```

Sheet `John Cena` has his data:

```
  | A              | B           | C                   |
1 | name           | category_id | experience_level    |
2 | Angular1.x     | 0           | 10                  |
3 | Apache Cordova | 1           | 5                   |
```

The problem is with validation step.

From UX perspective I want a developer to use validation drop-down so he can select a `category_id` value by text that is in `details!category`, but value that was placed should be a category_id. It should be so, so I could change the `category` text. For example when changing text `Web` to `Web framework` I want all sheets that where relating to `category` automatically updated with new text.

That was a first part. The next part, ideally, that when value is 0, cell should show value from `category`. This we operate with `category_id` through `category` text.

I search a lot, and got overwhelmed by amount of information about spreadsheet. So need some help from SO audience, if possible.

So the question is:

**Can validation custom user formula produce a drop-down list?** If yes, I need to feed a range of values for validation as result of that formala by using VLOOKUP. If no I need to create custom scenarios.

Comment: This question I created long time ago, custom macros for this feature I was considering as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understood the question correctly, but I'll try to answer them.

To your first question, the only way to do this is if you have a separate column that has a VLOOKUP for the catergory_id. This way if you modify the values in 'detail', all of the values will update. [image]

To your second question, for Data Validation one of the options for criteria is List from a Range. You can populate a given range however you want and if you select that range for data validation the dropdown will contain those values. This will update if the criteria range updates.